# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lj$/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: android, proguard

Crashlytics is detecting a crash on my app happening only on devices with Android 12:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lj$/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap;
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is that it could be related to proguard obfuscation.
I pasted my proguard config file here because it is too long for SO
https://pastebin.com/2yce7ZjR